# Query not working takes the previous date data also

Tags: c#, mongodb, iis-express

```cs
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        
DateTime nextDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
        
var filter1 = Builders.Filter.Gte(td => td.Txn_Date, currentDate) & Builders.Filter.Lt(td => td.Txn_Date, nextDate);
        
long count = _dbContext.TransactionDetails.CountDocuments(filter1);
```

This is my code but with current date it takes some data of previous date.

I tried doing with different method and with different dates. I just want count of current date.

Comment: Can you give an example of which transactions you want to include and which not?

Comment: I want the transaction count for current date all the transactions

Answer (score 0):

I've somehow successfully replicated the issue on my machine. According to your code, when you render the query, you will observe the following output:

```json
{
  "Txn_Date": {
    "$gte": ISODate("2023-10-06T18:30:00Z"),
    "$lt": ISODate("2023-10-07T18:30:00Z")
  }
}
```

I believe the problem lies with the usage of `currentDate`. To address this, I've made a modification by replacing `currentDate` with `DateTime.Now`, and I've applied the filter as follows: `Builders.Filter.Eq(td => td.Txn_Date, currentDate)`.

Below, you can find the complete code (please note that the order used in the code is hypothetical):

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        
        // DateTime nextDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
        
        var filter1 = Builders<Order>.Filter.Eq(td => td.Txn_Date, currentDate);

        var documentSerializer = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<Order>();

        var renderedFilter = filter1.Render(documentSerializer, BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry);

        Console.WriteLine(renderedFilter);
        
        // long count = _dbContext.TransactionDetails.CountDocuments(filter1);
    }
}

internal class Order
{
    public DateTime Txn_Date { get; set; }
}
```

Now, it filters based on the current date as demonstrated below:

```json
{
  "Txn_Date": ISODate("2023-10-07T11:51:05.968Z")
}
```

This should resolve the issue.